# Retrofit getting Datetime field from mysql database returns null

Tags: android, mysql, datetime, gson, retrofit

I am trying to get a Datetime field using Retrofit from mysql database.

This is the GsonBuilder and RestAdapter:

```
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().
            setEndpoint(MainActivity.baseUrl2).
            setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson)).
            build();
```

This is my inner class that parsed the JSON:

```
   public static class User {

        private String uid;
        private String name;
        private Date birthDate;
        private String username;
        private String path;
        private Date createdAt;
        private Object updatedAt;
        private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

.... getters();
..... setters();
}
```

So this system out command prints all the Dates as null:

```
            final LoginInfo.User userObject = loginInfo.getUser();
            System.out.println(userObject.getCreatedAt() + ", " + userObject.getUid() + ", "
            + userObject.getBirthDate() + ", " + userObject.getUpdatedAt());
```

> I/System.out﹕ null, 24, null, null

This is the returned JSON:

```
{
success: 1
unique_id: "54dfb704838680.85365105"
user: {
 uid: "24"
 name: "yy"
 birth_date: "2014-02-15"
 username: "ff"
 path: "http://192.168.1.10/ci2/user_pics/user24.jpg"
 created_at: "2015-02-14 22:58:44"
 updated_at: null
}-
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with php?

Comment: You aren't showing any JSON. Without this I can only assume that those fields are omitted from the JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way your code is set up, Gson thinks that while parsing it should look for fields `uid`, `name`, `birthDate` and so on. That's not good, because the actual fields in json are `uid`, `name`, `birth_date`, etc. That's the problem.

To properly map json to your object you should use `@SerializedName` annotation like so:

```
public static class User {
    private String uid;
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("birth_date")
    private Date birthDate;
    // ..
}
```

I would suggest you annotate every field of your class (even those, which names match with fields), because then it will eliminate problems with refactoring or Proguard, for example.